# A difference in spacing when \fontsize command is used

Tags: fonts, formatting, fontsize, overleaf, line-spacing

I use the following code

```
\settowidth\longest{\Large\itshape To my Parents, Teachers}
\begin{center}
\parbox{\longest}{%
  \raggedright{\Large\itshape%
  To my Parents, Teachers, \\ 
  Friends.
  \par\bigskip
  }   
  }
\end{center}
```

in a document with `\documentclass[12pt]{report}` and `\doublespacing`.

The fontsize `\Large` corresponds to 17pt, when the `documentclass` is defined to be `[12pt]`. I need to change the fontsize of the text to 24pt. So I tried using `\fontsize{24}{28.8}\selectfont` command (by having 1.2 × 24 = 28.8 to the second argument because I read that the baseline skip should be at least 1.2 × the font size).

When I use this command the double spacing disappears and the two lines of text gets much closer to each other.

Q1) Are the commands I've used correct? Is this difference occurring because of an error I did? Is this font size, 24pt same as the 24 fontsize used in MS Word?

Q2) Is there a way to fix this and have double spacing as required?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, in my case, the double space seems like behavior normally, you better provide the MWE all together can reproduce your problem.

Comment: you have just shown a fragment, not an example document anyone can debug.